# Access Matched Text at RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to escape `:` and `white space` at my regex. I tried that:

```
var re = new RegExp(':| ', 'g');   
var result = $(this).attr("id").replace(re, '\\${1}');
```

However it doesn't work. This is what I want to do:

```
Jack Kerouac => Jack\\ Kerouac 
Albert:Camus => Albert\\:Camus
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for braces use [`$&` to get the match within the string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) <strike>and use `\\\\` for double slash since `\\` produces single slash([one slash is for escaping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation))</strike>.

```
.replace(re, '\\$&');
```

```js
var str = `Jack Kerouac
Albert:Camus`;
var re = new RegExp(':| ', 'g');

console.log(str.replace(re, '\\$&'));
```

Comment: one doubt. How you add the hide/show snippet option

Comment: There are 2 more slashes instead of needed. Remove them to be accepted as answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can use pattern directly instead of instantiating with RegExp object.
also `\\` -> produce one `\` (escape), add `\\\\`

```js
var re = /\:|\s/g;  
var val1="fname lname";
var val2="fname:lname";
console.log(val1.replace(re,'\\\\$&'));
console.log(val2.replace(re,'\\\\$&'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This captures more than one space character:

```
s.replace( \(:| )+\g, '\\\\' )
```

You can play with more options here - https://regex101.com/r/WW67KE/1